# TypeScript breakpoints take a long time to start hitting when debugging in a Docker Container and VS Code

Tags: typescript, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am using the VS Code recipe from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Docker-TypeScript for debugging a Node.js Application in a Docker container. I have not made any changes to any of the settings in the template and followed the official instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes.git
cd vscode-recipes/Docker-TypeScript
npm install
code .
```

When I start the debugger with `Launch in Docker`, and set a breakpoint in the `index.ts` file, it takes anywhere between 63 - 68 seconds after I see the `Debugger attached.` message, before the set breakpoint(s) actually starts hitting. I can then set other breakpoints and they all work fine.  However, if I make changes to the file and save, this causes the debugger to reset the connection and I again have to wait the 30 seconds to 2 minutes, before breakpoints start hitting again.

I have tried this with a different project and I am seeing the same behavior. If I debug outside of the Docker container, breakpoints hit immediately.  This makes me thing it is somehow related to something in Docker.

Has anyone seen this? Any suggestions?

I am running:

```
Docker Desktop on a Mac  v2.2.0.5 (43884)
VS Code                  v1.44.2
macOS                    10.14.6 (cannot upgrade - work machine)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to correct this by changing the `timeout` value in the `launch.json`.

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch in Docker",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc-watch",
      "protocol": "auto",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [ "run", "docker-debug" ],
      "port": 5858,
      "restart": true,
      "timeout": 60000,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
      "remoteRoot": "/server/dist",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*"
      ],
      "trace": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
```

`timeout` refers to `Retry for this number of milliseconds to connect to Node.js. Default is 10000 ms.`. However, it doesn't seem like it is working as expected. It seems like it is instead waiting this long to check again if it is connected to the debugger.

So `"timeout": "60000"` meant that if the the debugger could not immediately connect, it will wait a whole minute before retrying.

Once I changed the value to `3000` and the breakpoints started hitting much sooner. The value should be sufficiently long to start up your container and `tsc-watch` task, otherwise you get an error that the debugger was not able to connect.

This can be avoided if you start the container before trying the debugger.

What I still can't explain is why it was saying `Debugger attached.`, yet the VS Code debugger was not really attached or at least it was not aware that it was attached.